# Soap SugarCRM Relationship between Leads and Calls

Tags: api, soap, sugarcrm, nusoap

I would like to create a relationship in SOAP call, to add an existing call to a lead.

I'm using this code and I get an error:

```
$rel_leacon = array(
    'session' => $session_id,
    'module_name' => 'Leads',
    'module_id' => $lead_id,
    'link_field_name' => 'Calls',
    'related_ids' => array($call_id),
    //'name_value_list' => array(),
    'delete' => 0
);

// set the product bundles products relationship
$rel_result = $client->call('set_relationship', $rel_leacon);

echo "Create Relationship Result<br />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rel_result); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The link name should be in lowercase.

Change:

```
'link_field_name' => 'Calls',
```

to:

```
'link_field_name' => 'calls',
```